# combination of independent random variables

Tags: probability

Let $X,Y,Z$ be 3 independent random variables following the normal gaussian law $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

I saw in an exercise that the random variable $X-2Y+Z$ follows the law $\mathcal{N}(0,6)$ but I don't figure out why?

What I did:

By linearity of the expected value:

$\mathbb{E}(X-2Y+Z)=\mathbb{E}(X)-2\mathbb{E}(Y)+\mathbb{E}(Z)=0$

By linearity of the variance for independent random variables:
$Var(X-2Y+Z)=Var(X)-2Var(Y)+Var(Z)=0$ so it doesn't follow the $\mathcal{N}(0,6)$ and I can't find my mistake.

Many thanks!

Comment: For variation, it should be $Var(aX+bY)=a^2Var(X)+b^2Var(Y)$ for independent $X$ and $Y$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variance is not linear in the sense that $Var(aX)=a^2Var(X)$. Then it follows that 
$$Var(X-2Y+Z)=Var(X)+(-2)^2Var(Y)+Var(Z)=6$$